# how to add delimiter to end of the each word in string using c#

Tags: c#

i have text file containing data like following.

4 4  4100100001063D 1CBSME 150312  40001063ANTE LECO METERING C 3460025.57LKR

i want add delimiter like following

4| 4|  4100100001063D| 1CBSME| 150312|  40001063ANTE| LECO| METERING| C| 3460025.57LKR|

how can i fix this problem. help me friends

Comment: What have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input = "4 4 4100100001063D 1CBSME 150312 40001063ANTE LECO METERING C 3460025.57LKR";
string pattern = "\\s+";
string replacement = "|";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement) + replacement;
```

This should replace all the spaces with "|" and then we are appending "|" to get expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Try *Linq*:

```
var target = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\Source.txt")
  .Select(line => line.Replace(" ", "| ") + "|");

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Target.txt", target);
```